# How to use ubuntu live disk to reset windows 10 password?

Tags: boot, password, windows-10

I need to reset the password of windows 10 for my little brother. There is a similar post on here on resetting vista password with chntpw. I followed the steps but it doesn't help. Anyone know how to do this without chntpw, a GUI program is preferred.

P.S. The final solution for me: [Reset windows 10 password with UUkeys](http://www.uukeys.com/reset-windows-10-password.html)

Answer (score 10):

1. Mount the Windows drive.
2. Rename `C:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe` to `sethc_bak.exe`
3. Copy `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and paste in the same DIR, renaming to `sethc.exe`
4. Reboot into Windows.
5. On the logon screen, press <kbd>shift</kbd> 5 times. You should now have an admin CMD prompt.
6. In the CMD window, type `net user your-user YourNewPassword` [replacing "your-user" & "YourNewPassword" accordingly.]
7. Once into the account, delete `C:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe`, and then rename `C:\Windows\System32\sethc_bak.exe` to `sethc.exe`.

---

I have done this in a VM, and it worked beautifully

Comment: Seems like TrustedInstall won't let you rename `sethc_bak`, so you'll have to do it from the live disc too.

Comment: @wjandrea - What version of Windows did you test with? This works fine for 7.

Comment: @AndroidDev Windows 10, as the question asks.

Comment: @wjandrea - OK, well thanks for the tip. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @wjandrea - But other than that it worked fine?

Answer (score -2):

I never did this with Ubuntu Live CD, but with ophcrack Live CD:
http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/

I tried a years ago, and I guarantee you that works fine in Windows XP and 7. I Never tried in windows 10. But you can try it and tell us. 
It's a GUI program.